# What is Div if not division

Tags: c++, c

```
size.total = size.width * size.height;
y = yuv[position.y * size.width + position.x];
u = yuv[(position.y / 2) * (size.width / 2) + (position.x / 2) + size.total];
v = yuv[(position.y / 2) * (size.width / 2) + (position.x / 2) + size.total + (size.total / 4)];
rgb = YUV444toRGB888(y, u, v);
```

> Here `/` is Div not division.

The above formula is taken from the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) link .

The one thing I want to know is that the statement mentioned

> Here `/` is Div not division.

What is *Div* here then, it is not dividing then what?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: I think they mean integer division.

Comment: Maybe they mean Divergence?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence

Comment: Divergence doesn't make sense in this context.  It's integer division like @gd1 said.

Comment: That page needs a bloody edit :)

Comment: I edited in the integer division. `Div not division` was confusing.

Comment: It's off-topic because it is about a poorly written Wikipedia article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the page means by Div is integer division.  In C, if both operands to the `/` operator are of an integral type, the result is also of an integral type and any fractional part is truncated.

For example, `5 / 2` evaluates to 2.

Comment: @asad-ali Does this answer your question?